# Enterprise Service Bus - UML diagrams

Tags: uml, esb, diagram

I have to present our latest IT system integration with Enterprise Service Bus including our Order/Invoice etc flows. However I have no idea which diagram/connections should I use.
In simple words our flow looks like
Order -> API -> ESB -> ERP
ERP -> Invoice -> ESB -> API -> Client
Each system has to do something with the input. Any hint would help me. I have already tried to use Class Diagram to present defined data structures and dependiencies + methods(presenting operations per system) on the other hand I am thinking about component diagram if it could be accurate for such presentation.

Answer (score 3):

The class diagram will indeed model the static structure of the domain object, such as `Order`, `Invoice`, `Customer` and how they relate to each other.

If you want to show the flows, i.e what happens when in which component of your super-system, the best way would be to use an activity diagram with partitions for the front-end, the ESB and the ERP.  Activity diagrams allow in particular to show object flows and buffers. A non-UML alternative for this is BPMN, but the expressivity of both notation is comparable.

If you want to show the details of the APIs, then you’d better think of sequence diagrams that allow to precisely model exchange of messages between different instances of classes  or components.

Comment: I agree, mostly. Treat the ESB as mere plumbing. (I have seen an ESB ripped out, so it may not even be permanent!) A message goes into the ESB and then each recipient magically receives a message that it handles.

Comment: IIRC there are SOA profiles that are usable for ESB. At least I have seen something for EA. Google gives some results for "UML SOA PROFILE".

Comment: @qwerty_so Ideed, even some interesting articles on that topic.

Comment: @JimL. Thanks for sharing this experience. I hesitated mentioning the ESB partition in the activity flow, because of the plumbing aspect. Nevertheless some ESB have some transformative functions (e.g. mapping) or error handling that may (or not) be useful to model. I leave it up to OP to see. Since API seems to be a concern here, I think the SD with an ESB instance could be useful. Because of the “ESB magic” it could perhaps help to show the interaction of ESB with different systems in different diagrams (separation of concerns, the ESB internals making the glue)

Comment: @qwerty_so Indeed, the OMG has a SoaML spec, which I indirectly contributed to. That used to be part of UPDM, but I believe it was taken out of the newer version of UPDM called UAF.  I don’t remember why.

Comment: @JimL. There must have been reasons ;-)

Comment: @Christophe: Is the expressivity of UML-ADs really comparable with the expressivity of BPMN? What about the distinction between synchronous "sequence flows" and asynchronous "message flows" in BPMN? And while BPMN does have a full-fledged concept of events, aren't events only treated in a rudimentary way in ADs?

Comment: @GerdWagner Thanks for your critical review. If both were equivalent, then one of them would be too much. My claim was to be understood in a limited scope (to which I believe OP’s problem belong). I think there were a couple of articles on the topic, such as: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228965384_A_Comparison_of_BPMN_and_UML_20_Activity_Diagrams . I also think I have once read an article about a converter but I cannot find it back.

Comment: @Christophe: Sure, there is a large overlap between the two languages, and in this (vague) sense, they are comparable, and it is strange that the more recent language standard, BPMN, doesn't refer back to the older language, UML-ADs, and explain the relationship between them. I think that BPMN is more expressive, mainly due to its elaborate concept of events and its distinction between  "sequence flows" and "message flows" (and the related distinction between intra-organizational and inter-organizational processes called "collaborations").

Comment: Thank you all for comments. Hopefully I will find any good way to present our architecture :)